# Posting build errors to slack or github

Tags: github, azure-devops, slack, azure-pipelines

I am using Visual Studio Online for continuous integration. I've also enabled integration with Slack (posting build status) and GitHub (validating pull requests).

In both of these integrations I am missing one feature - posting build error log to either Slack or GitHub (for example, as a comment to the pull request). This might substantially improve reaction time, since you don't need to go to the failed build (often re-login to VSO), find errors in the log, etc.

Did any of you guys manage to get this working somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**web hook**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks) to return VSTS build error message to slack or do some actions (create issue, close pull request etc) on github.

#### Prerequisite:

Web hook for VSTS build failed.

Develop a website to receive information, queue VSTS build and close pull request on github.

Add a build definition with [Post To Slack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=louisgerard.slackposter) task, when your VSTS build failed, your website will queue this build.

#### Create web hook:

VSTS project -> Service Hooks -> Create subscription -> Web hooks -> Next -> select Build completed to trigger this event -> select your CI build definition -> set Build Status to Failed -> Next -> set your website address to URL -> test if it works for your website -> Finish.

#### Develop functions on your website:

After your website receiving message from web hooks, trigger below actions:

1. Queuing the build with Post To Slack task by [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build).
2. Close a pull request on github by [REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request).