# Publish Azure DevOps pipeline artifact to Slack

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, slack, azure-artifacts

I have a pipeline on azure DevOps that creates and publishes an artifact (`releasenotes.txt`).

It also has integration with Slack using ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/slack?view=azure-devops ) .

How can i send `releasenotes.txt` to Slack? is it possible?

Comment: Please have a look at this thread for turnaround: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/publish-pipeline-artifact-to-slack

Answer (score 1):

> How can i send releasenotes.txt to Slack? is it possible?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid this is impossible to send `releasenotes.txt` file to Slack from Azure devops.

According to the Official document [Azure Pipelines with Slack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/slack?view=azure-devops), we could to know:

> If you use Slack, you can use the Azure Pipelines app for Slack to
>   easily monitor the events for your pipelines. **Set up and manage
>   subscriptions** for builds, releases, YAML pipelines, pending approvals
>   and more from the app and **get notifications for these events** in your
>   Slack channels.

In addition, if you check the extension [Slack Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.vss-services-slack), we can find the description:

> Slack is a **messaging app** for teams that makes their working lives
>   simpler, more pleasant, and more productive.
>
> Slack is a popular team collaboration service that helps teams be more
>   productive by **keeping all communications** in one place and easily
>   searchable from virtually anywhere.

So, Azure DevOps pipeline in the Slack is most used to **receive notifications** instead of the build pipeline itself.

On the other hand, if we frequently use the channel between Slack and Azure devops to transfer a large file (as opposed to notifications), this channel may be under high load, causing Slack to delay receiving other notifications, this is contrary to our original intention of integrating the azure pipeline together.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly, i think the people using DevOps realize that transferring large files over the internet can take time.
But if uploading a file is not an option, what about the option to add a string to the notification sent to slack?

Comment: @user1202032, There is no such out of box way to do that, you can use web hook to return a string to slack:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443184/posting-build-errors-to-slack-or-github

Comment: You have been very helpful, thank you, but the answer does not resolve my issue so i cannot mark it as accepted

Comment: If you think this feature is very important to you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/… ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.